# After programmatically creating a token, it does not get overridden

Tags: 6, tokens

I have the function below in a module. After it runs once, the token never changes again. I have to disable the module, and re-enable it, to get the token to run. Do you have any idea why this happens?

```
function my_token_values($type, $object = NULL, $options = array()) {
    global $user;

   $rand = rand();
   if ($type == 'global') {
        $tokens['random-number-replace'] = $rand;
   }
   return $tokens;
}
```

Comment: Consider trying a cache clearing instruction?

Comment: How does one do that in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a completely unrelated issue, but what was happening is that the token was getting set once, and then somewhere a custom module was checking if the token was set before setting it again.

Answer (score 2):

Where are you using the token? Drupal may be caching information at a higher level (like the filtered output of a node, for example) and only calling the token generation code once.